# FLEX mx:formitem multiple labels

Tags: apache-flex

I'm a new to Flex, and I'm trying to add a second label to a text box.

like this: Label [***_*__*_*___**] label 2

So the first label will describe the text box and the second the unit, for example:

cost of cleaning [***_*__*_*___**] $ per hour

Can I do this with a label inside the form item?

what I have tried looks like this:

```
            <mx:FormItem label="cost of cleaning">
                <mx:TextInput id="proSRO2YO" text="" width="120"  maxChars="20"/>
                <mx:Label text="dollars per hour"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
```

but that results in a second label one line below, I need these on the same line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why change the title to [SOLVED]? once you accept an answer, everyone can see that an answer has been accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [direction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/FormItem.html#direction) property and set it to horizontal.  the default is vertical.

```
        <mx:FormItem label="cost of cleaning" direction="horizontal">
            <mx:TextInput id="proSRO2YO" text="" width="120"  maxChars="20"/>
            <mx:Label text="dollars per hour"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
```